# Перегруппировать словари по одинаковому ключу

Tags: python

Прошу помочь.
Есть словарь:

```
{'feauture': 'Громкость звука', 'value': '0'}, 
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.0002'},
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.0003'},
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.0004'},
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.009'},
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.014'},
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.048'}, 
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.06'}, 
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.3'}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 3', 'value': '0.33'}, 
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.4'}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 2', 'value': '0.41'}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 2', 'value': '0.62'}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 1', 'value': '0.625'}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 2', 'value': '0.66'}, 
{'feauture': 'Макс. выход. ток', 'value': '0.660'}, 
{'feauture': 'Макс. выход. ток', 'value': '0.83'}, 
{'feauture': 'Макс. выход. ток', 'value': '1'}, 
{'feauture': 'Модульная ширина (общ. кол-во модульных расстояний)', 'value': '10'}, 
{'feauture': 'Макс. дальность действия', 'value': '100'}
```

Хочу привести к такому виду:

```
{'feauture': 'Громкость звука', ['0']}, 
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', ['0.0002', '0.0003', '0.0004', '0.009'.... ]},
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 3', ['0.33']}, 
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', ['0.4']}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 2', ['0.41', '0.62', '0.66']}}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 1', ['0.625']},
{'feauture': 'Макс. выход. ток', ['0.660', '0.83', '1']},
```

Необходимо сгруппировать по свойству товара и во вложенном словаре получить все значения этого свойства без повторений.

Comment: Ключи словаря уникальны `{'value': '0.0002', 'value': '0.0003'} == {'value': '0.0003'}`

Comment: Прошу прощения 
{'feauture': 'Громкость звука', {'0'}}, 
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', {'0.0002', '0.0003', '0.0004', '0.009'.... }},
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 3', {'0.33'}}, 
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', {'0.4'}}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 2', {'0.41', '0.62', '0.66'}}, 
{'feauture': 'Вторичный ток 1', {'0.625'}},
{'feauture': 'Макс. выход. ток', {'0.660', '0.83', '1'}},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

без внешних библиотек

```
data = [
    {'feauture': 'Громкость звука', 'value': '0'},
    {'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.0002'},
    {'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.0003'},
    # ...
]
```

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

key = itemgetter('feauture')
out = [{'feauture': k, 'value': [x['value'] for x in g]}
       for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=key), key=key)]
```

с помощью Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
out = df.groupby('feauture', as_index=False).agg(list).to_dict('records')
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативное решение:

```
from collections import defaultdict
t = defaultdict(set)
for feat in d:
    t[feat['feauture']].add(float(feat['value']))
```

Получим структуру словаря:

```
t = {'Вторичный ток 2': {0.62, 0.66, 0.41},
     'Макс. выход. ток': {0.66, 0.83, 1.0},
     'Вторичный ток 1': {0.625},
     'Модульная ширина (общ. кол-во модульных расстояний)': {10.0},
     'Громкость звука': {0},
     'Потребл. ток': {0.048, 0.06, 0.3, 0.014, 0.0004, 0.4, 0.0003, 0.009, 0.0002},
     'Вторичный ток 3': {0.33},
     'Макс. дальность действия': {100.0}}
```

Comment: d - это исходный список словарей

Answer (score 1):

В питоне можно пользоваться самим питоном и не вызывать библиотеки, о которых вы ранее ничего не слышали:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
dl = [
{'feauture': 'Громкость звука', 'value': '0'},
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.0002'},
{'feauture': 'Потребл. ток', 'value': '0.0003'},
...
]

res = dict()
for d in dl:
    if d['feauture'] not in res:
        res[d['feauture']] = {'feauture': d['feauture'], 'value': []}
    res[d['feauture']]['value'].append(d['value'])
print res.values()
```